# The left -hand and right hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the following error. I am not able to find out where exactly i went wrong.Can someone help me out with the solution

[image]

**The code**

```
 function() {
    this.devices.forEach(device => {
      let lastConnect = device.lastConnection.split('+');
      lastConnect = lastConnect[0] + 'Z';
      let diff = Math.abs(new Date() - new Date(lastConnect));//getting error here
}
```

Answer (score 183, accepted):

I have found out the issue.

The code you have written works only in **Javascript**

```
Math.abs(new Date() - new Date(lastConnect)) .
```

In order to make it work in **Typescript**, update the code as shown below:

```
Math.abs(new Date().getTime() - new Date(lastConnect).getTime());
```

Comment: why is this issue even happening? does Typescript not have a type Date? :/

Comment: @Herbertusz All valid javascript is valid Typescript. Typescript just allows devs to be more thoughtful with their type checking. Here Typescript is letting you know about using arithmetic on dates which at first glance doesn't sound logical, but we can do it anyway since all dates can be turned into some form of a representable number

Comment: Date().getTime() should be equivalent to `Date.now()`, right ?

Comment: No, `Date.now` is a static fn that returns the current time. `getTime()` is the time of an instance of `Date`, hence the `()` behind `Date`

Answer (score 24):

Needless to say, Your code works correctly in **Javascript**, If you want to get the same result in **Typescript**, You have **3** options

**(1) -** With the help of  `valueOf`

```
let diff = Math.abs(new Date().valueOf() - new Date(lastConnect).valueOf());
```

**(2) -** With the help of  `getTime`

```
let diff = Math.abs(new Date().getTime() - new Date(lastConnect).getTime());
// or
let diff = new Date().getTime() - new Date(lastConnect).getTime();
```

**(3) -** With the help of  `any`

```
let diff = Math.abs(<any>new Date() - <any>new Date(lastConnect))
```

Comment: technically valueOf and getTime is the same thing for dates, so I'd rather say it's better to use `getTime` because `valueOf` is js conversion-thing that used exactly for the cases when people do date1 + date2

Comment: for the simple fact that this well explained with three options, it is the best answer for me. I used getTime() though.

Answer (score 16):

The simplest answer would be

```
Math.abs(<any>new Date() - <any>new Date(lastConnect));
```

Answer (score 10):

No need for `Math.abs()` to answer this question...

Just using `getTime()` method converts a Date into a number ([Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)) so you can make the operation without that error

[Check on this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbr7ht)

Answer (score 8):

Another great way:

`Math.abs((new Date() as any) - (new Date(lastConnect) as any));`

Answer (score 4):

Typescript seems to have problems with implicit conversions, so we can just make them explicit:

```
Math.abs(+new Date() - +new Date(lastConnect));
```

Note that we don't need any parentheses because the `new` operator binds tighter than the (unary) `+` operator. After all, `(+new)` wouldn't make any sense. The `+` after the `-` is needed as well.

I'd use `any` only as a last resort since it basically disables typechecking.

Modifying a piece of code too much just to appease Typescript is not always safe as one may introduce errors because of wrong assumptions. This happens especially when one decides to convert some old .js files into .ts files. I think that making an implicit conversion explicit is the safest approach, in general.

Comment: Neat clean trick, although I'd still put a comment behind this line to explain to my fellow developers working on the same code ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue with `*ngIf="event && +event.enableSomething"`, as sometimes I'm receiving `"0"` data so parsing is needed but event interface was created for `enableSomething: boolean` so in that case I was retriving that error.

To fix this make sure that backend return boolean and leave `enableSomething: boolean` in interface or modify an interface to to `enableSomething: any`

I hope it helps someone with the same problem as occurred on my side.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I add `.valueOf()` after input of `Math.abs()`

```
Math.round(valA.valueOf() / 20)
```

according to de [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf):

> The `valueOf()` method returns the primitive value of the specified object.